# FTP check if directory exists on server or not

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I am running `backup.bat` script and used below command:

```
echo cd /public_html/GURUITSOFTWARESBACKUP>> ftpcmd.dat
```

I am getting reply `550`

> Can't change directory to /public_html/GURUITSOFTWARESBACKUP: No such file or directory

I need to change path to other directory in case if above path doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1):

This is hardly doable with a batch file and the Windows built-in `ftp`.

You better use some 3rd party FTP client. But even then, it is not easy to do any conditional processing in a batch file, unless you find an FTP client with a real scripting built-in (I'm not aware of any). Using a different scripting language than the batch file would be better option.

Anyway, if you use [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation), you can do something like this:

```
@echo off
 
set SESSION=ftp://username:password@example.com/
set REMOTE_PATH=/path/one
set REMOTE_PATH2=/path/two
winscp.com /command ^
    "open %SESSION%" ^
    "stat %REMOTE_PATH%" ^
    "exit"
 
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (
    echo Directory %REMOTE_PATH% exists, will use it
) else (
    echo Error or directory %REMOTE_PATH% not exists, will use %REMOTE_PATH2%
    set REMOTE_PATH=%REMOTE_PATH2%
)

echo Doing something with %REMOTE_PATH%
winscp.com /command ^
    "open %SESSION%" ^
    "cd %REMOTE_PATH%" ^
    "ls" ^
    "exit"
```

This is based on WinSCP article [Checking file existence](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_checking_file_existence).

---

The [article also shows](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_checking_file_existence#library) how to check for the [file/directory] existence using [WinSCP .NET assembly from a PowerShell script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell). That's what I would recommend.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*